# GDI+ Library on MAC

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, gdi+

I want to use basic GDI+ API's in MAC with CPP. (Libgdiplus is available on Linux)

Comment: Do you need to port an existing application or are you trying to write a new one ?

Comment: Check this question: [Is GDI+ compatible Linux and/or Mac?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101103061332AAUOXHz)

Answer (score 3):

GDI+ is a Microsoft library for Windows. The linux "libgdiplus" that you refer to is targeted to X11 via Cairo, and will *not* work on Mac OS X, though you may be able to use the same code if you intend to use an X11 session under OS X (i.e. not for native OS X apps).

There is no native OS X port of GDI+ that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

You should write your drawing code using Core Graphics, the native graphics architecture on Mac OS X and iOS, rather than use a port of a technology from another platform.

Comment: Hi Chris,

Thank you for suggestion.
Can you share any of sample code

Comment: There are a ton of examples showing how to use Core Graphics in the Mac and iOS documentation.